# Python String Accessing

Tags: python, string, character

I am helping a friend with Python and I might be getting confused with C++. So I am curious as to why this would not work. The expected function of this is a Pig Latin translator so if there is a vowel as the first letter 'ay' is added to the end but if the first letter is a consonant, that letter is added to the end and then the 'ay' is added. 
Example:
apple --> appleay
watch --> atchway
Sorry I completely forgot to post the code (edit)

```
vowel = ['a','e','i','o','u']
counter = -1
while True: 
    text = input("Write a word to translate. If you do not want to play anymore, 
write exit: ")
if text == "exit":
    break  

elif text[0].lower() in vowel:
    text = text + 'ay'
    print(text)

elif text[0].lower() not in vowel:
    letter = text[0]
    length = len(text) - 1
    for i in range(1, length):
        text[i-1] = text[i]
    text[length + 1] = letter
    print(text)
```

Comment: Where is the function?

Comment: Could you post the code you have so far?

Comment: So the consonant is removed from the first letter as well?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to add the code.

Answer (score 1):

Strings are immutable, so you can't assign to a string at specific index like `text[i-1] = text[i]`.

Instead, use `text = text[1:] + text[0] + 'ay'` to do what you want:

```
vowel = ['a','e','i','o','u']
counter = -1
while True:
    text = input("Write a word to translate. If you do not want to play anymore, write exit: ")
    if text == "exit":
        break

    elif text[0].lower() in vowel:
        text = text + 'ay'
        print(text)

    elif text[0].lower() not in vowel:
        text = text[1:] + text[0] + 'ay'
        print(text)
```

Comment: You can just use else for text[0].lower() not in vowel , I think.

Comment: I know that that is an option but is there a way for me to individually access the indices of the string and reassign the value like how I tried to do in my original code?

Comment: @RyanMarvin If you want to do it in your original way, you can cast the string to a list first (like `letters = str(text)`) so that you can assign values to it at specific indexes, and then convert the list back with `join` (like `''.join(letters)`).